# The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, development-environment, homestead

I'd like to use `laravel homestead` for my development machine and installed virtualbox and vagrant successfully, but when I run `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

The `Homestead.yaml` file looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

These are the default settings, but they don't really work for my machine - I don't even have `/home/vagrant` folder nor do I have `~/Code` anywhere  where I can see. I'm using `ubuntu 12.04` - can you please point me to how I should configure my settings because by the official documentation I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Did you try creating a folder `Code` in your root directory? Of your local machine, that is, not in the virtual one. Homestead is complaining that it can't find that directory, so it can't connect `/home/vagrant/Code` within the virtual machine to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your Ubuntu machine you have to let Homestead know where your actual code is located. Example:

If you code is located in a seperate partition called WORKSPACE you need to type the following:

```
    - map: /Volumes/WORKSPACE/YourProject
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Comment: I followed your answer, and I still get the error `* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`

Comment: I configure mine like this : `folders:
    - map: ~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant//Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aveniros/Laravel/public`

Comment: how I can know, where is my code located? i.e. how to know what wil be the value of `map:`

Comment: value of `map` is you **local** code folder. How can I be that you not know where your code is?

Answer (score 19):

Inside the homestead directory, you have to run the command `bash init.sh`.

This will generate the `Homestead.yaml` file (and `after.sh` and `aliases`) inside your home directory (`~`).

If you are changing `Homestead.yaml` again, you have to re-run `bash init.sh` again. It will ask for overwrite, say yes.

(and as mentioned in other answers, be sure that the directory for `folders: - map:` exists)

Comment: running bash init.sh again overridden the values back to default...in my case i just edited and saved the file and this was it.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows case I used this:
**- map: e:/GIT/PHP/mathmaps/Code

    to: /home/vagrant/Code**

P.S. GIT is my workspace folder

Answer (score 1):

running bash init.sh a second time will prompt to overwrite the initial setup, this will also output the directory path you require to edit the correct Homestead.yaml file.

Answer (score -1):

The map: attribute has to be set to the location to where you want to keep your code. For example, I will be saving my code in a folder called code within the Homestead folder therefore, map is:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Development/Homestead/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Where 'Development' is simply a folder in my home directory where I keep all my code

Comment: Has been answered before. The answer has been accepted.